# What is meant by MY COMMISSION EXPIRES?

Tags: forms

I'm trying to fill out the electronic verification form to get an EFS account. https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/Patent%20Electronic%20System%20Form.pdf

At the very end of the doc, it says MY COMMISSION EXPIRES: what does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

The bottom portion is for a notary public to stamp, certifying that the signature belongs to who it purports to belong to. They are the ones with a commission that will expire at some point.

Comment: thanks for the reply. So can I just leave this blank?

Comment: @jackedimimuschadimimus No you have to get it notarised before sending it to the USPTO. Let the Notary fill Block 5.